# How do I print a truncated key-value pair in Python?

Tags: python, key-value, truncation

I am a just starting with coding and I am trying to solve a challenge. The challenge is to write a function that when given an key value pair with a title and url, the function will print a linked title.

If the title is longer than 50 characters, truncate the title to 50 characters followed by 3 ellipses.

I am trying to do this in Python. Below is what I have so far. I realize the last part is just floating there. I wasn't sure where to put it though.

I was trying to create a class that I could add the key-value pair to as i will have to add more in the next challenge.

```
class Webpage(object):
    def __init__(self, title, link):
        self.title = title
        self.link = link
    ex1 = ('really, really, really long title that will be chopped off', 'example.com')
        print Webpage.ex1

title = (title[:50] + '..' if len(title) > 50 else title)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The code you've written should work, you just need to put it into a class method. Then it should use `self.title` to get the title from the class.

Comment: so is your question how to retrieve the webpage?

Comment: @Matti Lyra The output should be the link and the truncated title. But when I run it I get a "command not found" error.

Comment: @Barmar How would I put it in a class method?

Comment: `def print_title(self):` followed by the code to print the title. Any tutorial on writing classes in Python should explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intuition is that all you want is something simple, like this.

```
>>> class Webpage(object):
...     def __init__(self, title, link):
...         self.title = title
...         self.link = link
...     def print_title(self):
...         print (self.title[:50] + '..' if len(self.title)>50 else self.title)
... 
>>> webpage_1 = Webpage('little title', 'http://www.somewhere.org')
>>> webpage_1.print_title()
little title
>>> webpage_2 = Webpage('big title' + 50*'-', 'http://www.somewhere.org')
>>> webpage_2.print_title()
big title-----------------------------------------..
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a different variable for the displayed truncated title and then use [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) to return the property attribute.

```
class Webpage(object):
    def __init__(self, title, link):
        self.title = title
        self.link = link
        self._truncated_title = (self.title[:50] + '..' if len(self.title) > 50 else self.title)
    @property
    def print_title(self):
        """returns the truncated title"""
        return self._truncated_title
example = Webpage('really, really, really long title that will be chopped off', 'example.com')
print(example.print_title)
```

Hope this helps!